# Dynamic Arary in C++ with pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, dynamic

I want to sort the Array in Dynamic Way with Pointers , but The Output does not correct ,, why I don't know ,, So Please Can You Check this Code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    int temp,i,j,*p1,n,t;
    cin>>n;
    p1 = new int [n];   

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>*p1;
        p1++;
        }
        p1-=n;

    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        if(*(p1+i) > *(p1+j))
        {
            temp = *(p1+i);
            *(p1+j) = *(p1+i);
            *(p1+j) = temp;
        }
        p1++;
    }
    p1-=n-1;

    cout<<"--------------------\n\n";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<p1[i]<<"\t";

    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I do Like That It's Work

*(p1+i) changed to p1[i]

*(p1+j) changed tp p1[j]

But Why with Pointer with Star Not Work ? !

Comment: I doubt that it works with `[]`.

Comment: "Works" is quite different from works.

Comment: You can use `p1[i]` instead of `*(p1+i)`. It will be much easier, especially if p1 is a int* const, you can be sure that it does not moves. Btw. Do you know, you can use std :: sort with comparator?

Comment: @Tacet, The comparator isn't even necessary. The algorithm is most assuredly leaps and bounds ahead of bubble sort, too.

Comment: @chris Right, I was still thinking about it, like about array of pointers (after the title). Sorry, my bad. `std::(p1,p1+n)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is error:

```
temp = *(p1+i);
*(p1+j) = *(p1+i);
*(p1+j) = temp;
```

it should be:

```
temp = *(p1+i);
*(p1+i) = *(p1+j); // NOTE you're assign to Ith from Jth
*(p1+j) = temp;
```

UPDATE: remove second `p1++;` and `p1-=n-1;`

Comment: This is why it should just be `std::swap(p1[i], p1[j]);`.

Comment: And also `p1++;` shouldn't be there.

Comment: But Why When I Remove p1++; and p1-=n-1, Should not use p1++ with star pointer , Please Can Answere Me

Comment: @user3369307 you're using indexs (i, j) in second loop, so you cannot change "base" (p1). in first loop vice versa - you'are not using indexes, but changing p1